# Extract class type collection with lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, collections, dst

I have a collection as shown below

```
public classCol1: Collection<A>
{
}

public class A
{
     public B1 a;
     public B2 b;
}

public class B1
{
     public MG m;
}

public class MG
{
    public E e;
    public BR b;
    public DST d;
}
```

I want to select from collection Col1, where MG does not contain DST. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what's the collection? you've shown only classes and no collections...

Comment: `collectionOfA.Where(item => item.a.m.d == null)`

Comment: "does not contain DST" means it's null? it's equal to a certain value? you're not being clear here...

Comment: DST is not null, it has some value

Comment: so what do you mean by "MG does not contain DST"? instances of MG where DST is null? DST is set to default? you're not clear with your request...

Comment: @VikashRanjanJha - Have the answer bellow help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
Col1 collection = new Col1();
var results = collection.Where(item => item.a.m.d != null);
```